# Web scraping a table: Error using rvest and splash

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table from this link (https://www.sac-isc.gc.ca/eng/1620925418298/1620925434679). I have tried two approaches so far:

1. Using rvest though I couldn't find HTML nodes on the page for the table
2. Using splash, assuming the page is being loaded dynamically

Neither of the approaches seem to be working for me. After hours of trying and reading posts/blogs, etc, I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. Can someone please point me to the right direction or atleast tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Scraping using rvest:

```
library(rvest)

loadedTable <- read_html("https://www.sac-isc.gc.ca/eng/1620925418298/1620925434679") %>%

html_nodes("table") %>%

html_table() %>%

as.tbl()
```

Error:

```
Error in matrix(unlist(values), ncol = width, byrow = TRUE) :

'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Scraping using splashr:

```
library(splashr)
library(reticulate)

install_splash()

splash("localhost") %>% splash_active()

sp <- start_splash()

pg <- render_html(url = 'https://www.sac-isc.gc.ca/eng/1620925418298/1620925434679')

stop_splash(sp)

loadedTable1 <- pg %>% 
  html_node('table') %>% 
  html_table()

loadedTable1
```

Error:

```
Did not find required python module 'docker'
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to localhost port 8050: Connection refused
Error in stop_splash(sp) : object 'sp' not found
Error in html_element(...) : object 'pg' not found
Error: object 'loadedTable1' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pulled dynamically from another URI. There is some work to do to write a process to extract just what you see on the page, or whatever you actually want to see, as there is a lot of info brought back, including all the `more detail`.

The unix timestamp on the end is largely about prevent cached results being served. You can generate that and sprintf it into the rest of the url.

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://www.sac-isc.gc.ca/DAM/DAM-ISC-SAC/DAM-WTR/STAGING/texte-text/lTDWA_map_data_1572010201618_eng.txt?date=1622135739812')
```

To access all info about First Nation `Kapawe'no`, for example, you would do the following:

```
print(data$data[82])
```

Comment: Examine the list under data$data e.g. index 1 and write a parsing function for your desired output format. See results as tree here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?#left=cloud.55f0755dbad64a7b95f1ab0725bd6a49

Comment: Thanks Qharr! As this generates a list of lists, I'd only want to pull LTDWACurrent and LTDWALifted (whichever is not null), pieces from it for each ID. Is there a library that helps truncate and help me achieve this?

Comment: 1/2 Hiya! So, it is not always an Either/Or. [This](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?#left=cloud.55f0755dbad64a7b95f1ab0725bd6a49) is all the data from the table. If you look at #11 in that 0-based list, ID 13, Mississaugas you will see there are 4 current and 1 lifted. You can also see this by doing `data$data[[12]]$LTDWACurrent` and `data$data[[12]]$LTDWALifted` or by expanding the table on the website to show more results. Please can you review the expanded table against the link I have provided above and then tell me how those results should be shown (in full).

Comment: 2/2 In that example, it looks like `Water System Name` is an import differentiator.